# Cannot mount volumes to jenkins helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to mount existing google cloud Persistent Disk(balanced) to Jenkins in Kubernetes.
In the root of the disk located fully configured Jenkins. I want to bring up Jenkins in k8s with already prepared configuration on google Persistent Disk.

I'm using latest chart from the https://charts.jenkins.io repo

Before run `helm install` I'm applying pv and pvc.

**PV** for existent disk:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: jenkins-persistent-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  csi:
    driver: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
    volumeHandle: projects/Project/zones/us-central1-a/disks/jenkins-pv
    fsType: ext4
```

**PVC**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-pvc
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  volumeName: jenkins-persistent-volume
  accessModes:
    - "ReadWriteOnce"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: "50Gi"
```

[image: pv]
[image: pvc]

Files in Persistent Google Disk are 100% **1000:1000** permissions (uid, gid)

I made only one change in official helm chart, it was in values file

```
  existingClaim: "jenkins-pvc"
```

After running `helm install jenkins-master . -n jenkins`
I'm getting next:
[image: failed pod]

Just for ensure that problem not from GCP side.
I mount pvc to busybox and it works perfect.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: busybox
      image: busybox:1.32.0
      command:
        - "/bin/sh"
      args:
        - "-c"
        - "while true; do echo $(date) >> /app/buffer; cat /app/buffer; sleep 5; done;"
      volumeMounts:
        - name: my-volume
          mountPath: /app
  volumes:
    - name: my-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: jenkins-pvc
```

[image: busybox]

I tried to change a lot of values in values.yaml also tried use old charts, or even **bitnami charts** with deployment instead of stateful set, but always error is the same.
Could somebody shows my the right way please.

**Storage classes**
[image: storage classes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set the `podSecurityContextOverride` and re-install:

```
controller:
  podSecurityContextOverride:
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsNonRoot: true
    supplementalGroups: [1000]
persistence:
  existingClaim: "jenkins-pvc"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! 
In the combination of your comment and the comment below Jenkins started working.

Comment: The busybox test you did prove that the issue is not related to StorageClass.

Answer (score 1):

Change storageClass

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: jenkins-persistent-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
```

to `default`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: jenkins-persistent-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: default
```

Also check your existing storageClasses:
`kubectl get sc`

Alternatively, set storageClass to "" in values:

```yaml
global:
  imageRegistry: ""
  ## E.g.
  ## imagePullSecrets:
  ##   - myRegistryKeySecretName
  ##
  imagePullSecrets: []
  storageClass: "" # <-
```

*I would have post it in comment, but too low repution to comment*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't help. already tried with empty value

Comment: when the value is empty after applying it would automatically set to "standard"

Comment: can you post your storageClass? `kubectl get sc`

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! 
In the combination of your comment and the comment above Jenkins started working.